# Printing random lines in .txt file using random.sample() Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I have a text file with 15 quotes per line. 
My goal is to print not one but two random quotes to the console. My code works, however its the formatting I have an issue with.

I would like to print the quotes line by line so its clean and easily readable.
But the code I have prints in a list format.. e.g. with square brackets '[]' quotation marks '' and '\n'.

Code:

```
import random
def primary():
  f = open("quotes.txt")
  quotes = f.readlines()
  f.close()

  sampling = random.sample(quotes, 2)
  print(sampling)


if __name__== "__main__":
  primary()
```

Result:

```
['Truth is stranger than fiction\n', 'Anything added dilutes everything else\n']
```

I'm sure defining the function to print according to index numbers in some way will resolve but not sure how.

Comment: `sampling` is a list, so it's printed as a list. To output individual elements, loop over this list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :)

```
import random
def primary():
  f = open("quotes.txt")
  quotes = f.readlines()
  f.close()

  sampling = random.sample(quotes, 2)
  for sample in sampling: print(sample)


if __name__== "__main__":
  primary()
```